# SVG filters: adjust color channels

Tags: svg, svg-filters, css-filters

Looking to adjust the tonal values of the green color channel in an image. Specifically, changing the green values (only) to really dark green or black. Any ideas using svg filters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the [SVG `feColorMatrix`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#feColorMatrixElement) with `type="matrix"`. Then discard the Red/Blue channels, and multiply the green-to-green to be darker.

Specifically, to turn an RGBA image to use just the green channel and darken it by half (and have full alpha no matter what the original alpha was), you want these matrix values:

```c
/*R   G   B   A   1 */
  0   0   0   0   0   // R = 0*R + 0*G   + 0*B + 0*A + 0*1
  0  0.5  0   0   0   // G = 0*R + 0.5*G + 0*B + 0*A + 0*1
  0   0   0   0   0   // B = 0*R + 0*G   + 0*B + 0*A + 0*1
  0   0   0   0   1   // A = 0*R + 0*G   + 0*B + 0*A + 1*1
```

### Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hkah9w4d/2/

```xml
<filter id="darkGreen">
  <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0  0  0 0 0
                                       0 0.5 0 0 0
                                       0  0  0 0 0
                                       0  0  0 0 1" />
</filter>
```

You don't have to line up the values in a grid like that, but I prefer to do so in order to make it more clear what's going on, and make it easier to edit.

Alternatively, you could use:

```xml
<feComponentTransfer>
  <feFuncR type="linear" slope="0" />
  <feFuncG type="linear" slope="0.5" />
  <feFuncB type="linear" slope="0" />
</feComponentTransfer>
```

---

**Edit**: re-reading your question, I wonder if perhaps you wanted to leave the red and blue channels intact. If so, you want values like the following, which copy red-to-red and blue-to-blue, but darken the green channel to 40% of its original brightness:

```xml
<filter id="darkenGreen">
  <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="1  0  0 0 0
                                       0 0.4 0 0 0
                                       0  0  1 0 0
                                       0  0  0 0 1" />
</filter>
```

### Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hkah9w4d/7/

Alternatively, you could use:

```xml
<feComponentTransfer>
  <feFuncG type="linear" slope="0.4" />
  <!-- the other channels will default to type="identity" -->
</feComponentTransfer>
```

Comment: You also may be interested in comparing the differences between using just green-to-green versus RGB-to-green: http://jsfiddle.net/hkah9w4d/6/

Comment: Using different weightings on the RGB channels is an attempt to gather the true luminance of the image; you can see an example of this (and some good weighting values) in the `luminanceToAlpha` option described in the `feColorMatrix` docs linked in my answer.

Comment: Thanks!! BTW - do you know of any way to adjust the feColorMatrix values after an image is converted to grayscale? (Kind of like how photoshop does it.)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your desire. Could you clarify your input and desired result?

Comment: In general, you can modify the matrix values on the fly using JavaScript, and the results will be updated. For example see: http://jsfiddle.net/hkah9w4d/8/