# Changing Contrast and Saturation for a given Color Channel in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, filter, contrast, hsb

I know how to build color channels in JavaScript (iterate through an image and place each color value in an array). I would like to be able to change Contrast and Saturation for a given color channel.  For example, use the CSS3 Contrast or Saturation filter to apply changes only to the Red channel.

Thank you

PS: I'm staying with Pure JavaScript here (no 3rd party libraries).

Comment: Post what you've tried or the stage you've gotten to or better yet a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I really don't have anything yet, just creating the RGBA color channels by iterating and storing the values in an array.

Answer (score 0):

This would appear to answer my question: Using an SVG filter to access the color channels and then manipulating the color channels with the feColorMatrix filter:

[SVG filters: adjust color channels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28097128/svg-filters-adjust-color-channels)